# How do I get the single element from the text file by using ArrayList?

Tags: java

My text file includes:

- Mary,123,s100,59.2
- Melinda,345,A100,10.1
- Hong,234,S200,118.2
- Ahmed,678,S100,58.5
- Rohan,432,S200,115.5
- Peter,654,S100,59.5

My code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("competitors.txt")) ;
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            lines.add(line);
        }          
        String[] lineobject= {lines.get(0)};
        System.out.println(lineobject[0]);
  }
}
```

I don't know why it can not get the single value of first row, can anyone help?Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of your code?

Comment: What output do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lines.get(0) is "Mary,123,s100,59.2", not {"Mary","123","s100","59.2"}

So you should do;

```
String[] lineobjects = lines.get(0).split(",");
System.out.println(lineobjects);
System.out.println(lineobjects[0]); // prints "Mary"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. However, you should make sure to place the file competitors.txt in the right directory.

This is simpler and should also do the job:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("competitors.txt"));
    System.out.println(lines.get(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may replace the line with some another signs instead of using`,` (I use `%`in my case),and split using`.split("%")`,Then store in a vector file..

```
            Vector data;
            Vector columns;
            String line;
                data = new Vector();
                columns = new Vector();

    try {
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(PRJT_PATH+"\\YOUR\\PROJECT\\"+PATH);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                        StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), " ");
                        while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
                                columns.addElement(st1.nextToken());
                        int i=0;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                                StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                                while (st2.hasMoreTokens()){
                                        data.addElement(st2.nextToken());}
                                String clr[]=line.split("%");
                                Vector v=new Vector();

                                v.add(clr[0]);
                                v.add(clr[1]);
                                i++;
                        }
                        br.close();
                        fis.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.getMessage();
                }
```